# Run Python scraping script on a server

Tags: python, web-scraping, automation

I apologize ahead of time, as this may seem like a ridiculous question.  I have used Python for the purposes of regex, automation and leveraging pandas for work.  I would now like to run a web scraping script (nothing special, < 50 lines, 24 hours a day, which i think i will need server access for to do so(can't run on laptop if laptop is shut while i am sleeping) for personal use, but I have no idea how to go about this?

Would i need to rent a virtual machine, physical server space?  My intent is to run the script and send an email with the results, its all very low tech and low capacity, more of a notification.  How does one go about modifying their code to do something like this and then what kind of server access would i need?  any suggestions would be helpful!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNIX style approach to the problem:

1. Rent a server ( VPS ) - you can find something for $2.5-$5
2. Create and upload your scraping script to the server
3. Create crontab ( tool that's responsible for executing your script on regular basic - say once per hour or whatever you want )
4. Use https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.html package for sending emails from Python